# Introducing behavioural states into hidden markov model?

Tags: hidden-markov-model, state-space-models

I have a hidden markov model which models movement. A map is split into even sized grids and the hidden states are the grids.

I want to improve this model by adding behavioural states (so that movement is different if the data suggests the animal is in a different behavioural state). However, I have no idea how this can be done.

Any guidance would be appreciated, I hopefully would like to implement this in R.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to include external variables to influence HMM. Use heterogeneous HMM. you will get transition probability as a function of external variables ( behavior state in your case). DepmixS4 is the best package to implement in R.-

This article is without external variable, but a good start.

http://machinelearningstories.blogspot.com/2017/02/hidden-markov-model-session-1.html